# Python3 script: tunnel does not work though Wireshark detects packet

Tags: python, networking

I am working on implementing a tunnel program in Python.
I am testing this program with a device that periodically sends a message and expects a reply from a Python script running on my laptop.
The Python script is as follows:

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM

# receiving
UDP_in_IP = "::"
UDP_in_PORT = 61624

sock_in = socket(AF_INET6, # Internet
                        SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock_in.bind((UDP_in_IP, UDP_in_PORT))

# forwarding
UDP_out_PORT = 61624

sock_out = socket(AF_INET6, # Internet
                        SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
numb = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock_in.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    my_bytes = bytearray()
    my_bytes.append(numb)
    my_bytes.append(69 & 0xff)
    my_bytes.append(69 >> 8)
    reply = my_bytes
    sock_out.sendto(reply, (addr[0], UDP_out_PORT))
    print("forwarding message:", reply, addr)
    numb = numb +1
```

I have a version of the working tunnel in Python 2. With this tunnel, the device correctly sends to my laptop and Wireshark both captures its message and the response, see screenshot.
[image]

With the other version of the working tunnel, in Python 3, it only receives the message of the device. According to Wireshark, see image, this message is as good as identical (not withstanding payload and checksum) but my script does not reply to it.

[image]

I am at a total loss why this is so. Both the old tunnel and new tunnel are fairly big pieces of code, making it difficult to place potentially relevant pieces here. Using a debugger, I have been able to confirm that both do the following on receiving a message from the device, after which Wireshark captures the device message.

In old tunnel, Python 2:

```
def send(self,data):
    self.log.debug('Sent to network')
    string = chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(134)+chr(221)+data
    os.write(self.virtualIf,chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(134)+chr(221)+data)
```

In new tunnel, Python 3:

```
def send(self,data):
    # add 4B tun header
    formatted_data = bytes(chr(134)+chr(221), encoding='utf-8') + data
    print('[NetworkSideThread] Sent packet to network \n')

    os.write(self.virtualIf, formatted_data)
```

Any clue what is happening wrongly?

Edit: addendum, doing ifconfig to see if the tunnels are similar reveals it is so. The top one is the old tunnel, the bottom one the new.

[image]

Edit:
I'm also noticing that the 'any'-interface of wireshark captures from/to traffic when using the old tunnel and **no** traffic when using the new tunnel.
The from/to traffic has an additional linux cooked capture header when captured by the 'any'-interface. No clue if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The problem was NOT with the tunnel but with how the packets were written to the tunnel.

I should have added, or not required, a tunnel header before writing the packet to the tunnel.